# The password-answer supplied is invalid (Asp.net mvc 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

How can i fix this problem? Where can i change the password requirement in my project so that it also accept simple password?

I've encounter this problem after I ran `update-database` in package manager console. I've searched around but found no answers to this problem (maybe I'm not looking long enough).  There were solutions but it was for asp.net mvc 4 and below.  I'm using mvc 5 and i see no `membership` tag in `Web.config` file.  Here is the problem:

[image]

As you can see, the error is in `Configuration.cs` file at line 33, and here is that code (I believe it's the `Membership.CreateUser` that create this problem?)

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve (and what the question is); it seems that the password answer is needed to create a user, and the Seed method of your migration does not supply this information. Do you want to change the requirement for the password answer? Do you want to add a dummy password answer?

Comment: I think that my password is not strong enough so I guess I want to change the requirement, but if there's a way to add a dummy password, that would be helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the configuration of your membership provider from WEB.CONFIG?

Comment: Hi, as i mentioned, there is no membership tag in my web config file in the root folder.

Comment: Is this a seeding migration?

Comment: Password is weak. Just go to definition of Membership Press F12 and change the Password Attribute Validation.

Comment: Yes, it is seeding migration.. I will try once i get home.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution.  I have to change the configurations in `IdentityConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder.

[image]

Comment: Please, if you are still active, edit this answer to include the code as text, not an image.